# Применить стиль к элементу с определенным уровнем вложенности

Tags: html, css, html5, вёрстка, css3

Допустим у нас есть такие элементы:

```html
<div class="block">
  <p>
    <span>
      ....
    </span>
  </p>  
</div>
```

Что бы добраться до `p` элемента относительно `div` с классом `block`, мы делаем так:

```css
.block > p {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Как поступают если необходимо добраться до элемента `span` относительно элемента `div` с классом `block` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого ничего ставить не нужно

```css
div.block span {color: red}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <p>
    <span>
      ....
    </span>
  </p>  
</div>
```

Или вот так:

```css
div.block > p > span {color: red}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <p>
    <span>
      ....
    </span>
  </p>  
</div>
```

---

### Доп. информация

Что бы обратится к соседнему, поставить нужно `+`:

```css
.block {width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: black;}
.block + .block {background-color: red;}
```

```html
<div class="block"> 
</div>
<div class="block">
</div>
```

И что бы обратится ко всем правым соседним элементам, ставится `~`:

```css
.block {width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: black;}
.block ~ .block {background-color: red;}
```

```html
<div class="block"> 
</div>
<div class="block">
</div>
<div class="block">
</div>
<div class="block">
</div>
```

Что бы обратится к определённому элементу, ставится `:nth-child`:

```css
.block {width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: black;}
.block:nth-child(3) {background-color: red;}
```

```html
<div class="block"> 
</div>
<div class="block">
</div>
<div class="block">
</div>
<div class="block">
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за подробности

Comment: @perfect, или вы что-то другое имели введу?

Comment: именно это я и хотел

Comment: @perfect, и для общего развития. Сейчас используют такую систему классификации: https://ru.bem.info/methodology/

Comment: @perfect BEM — методология, а не классификация. `+` — селектор непосредственного соседа справа. Селектор любого соседа справа — `~`.

Answer (score 2):

Можно, как Вы и написали.

```
.block > p > span {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

А можно и так:

```
.block span {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Первый селектор выбирает прямого потомка. Т.е. стили будут применены ко всем элементам span, которые находятся в элементе p, который, в свою очередь, вложен в контейнер с классом .block.

Второй селектор выбирает не прямых потомков, а всех. Т.е. стили применятся ко всем элементам span, которые вложены в контейнер с классом .block не важно на каком уровне.

Comment: спасибо за подсказку я думал такой синтаксис только jquery использует